# Expo: Lotties exception after upgrade to SDK 33 of expo

Tags: react-native, expo, lottie

I have upgraded to SDK 33 of my Expo and run my iOS application but receive this warning. What does mean? and how do overcome this? Looks like android does not have this issue showing up.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the issue via this link: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/4455

And you can ignore this warning like this:

> import { YellowBox } from "react-native";
>
> YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(["ReactNative.NativeModules.LottieAnimationView.getConstants"]);

The ignore solution is cited from https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/4455#issuecomment-502631736